# Dryer Cord will not go in all the way

Tags: dryer

I just moved to a new construction house. I brought my four-prong dryer cord along from my previous house and it matches up perfectly. But when I try to plug it in, it goes in about half way and will not go in any further. I checked the breaker and it was tripped off. I reset it but that didn't help. What am I doing wrong?

It appears the east and west sockets are preventing the plug from getting all the way in. There is a small slit in each about halfway in but it does not seem wide enough to accommodate the prongs. Could that be a defect in the outlet?

Comment: Some of the newer receptacles can be a little difficult to get all the way in, you may need to push a little harder. If that does not work call and have it replaced.

Comment: It sounds like either plug, receptacle, or both is outta spec....

Comment: If you rock the plug back and forth, does it appear that a specific one of the prongs is the one preventing further progress? If you pull out the plug, can you see any difference in that prong or its receptacle? (And, don't run the dryer if you can't get the plug all the way in.)

Comment: Can you post some photos?

Comment: I could add, from own experience, that a new receptacle can require a good amount of pressure to get the plug in the first few times. After that it can become easier. But, as others have also said, a new receptacle could also be faulty and need replacement. It is likely that a new outlet was placed by the installer and never actually checked out by having something plugged into it.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. The dryer does run if I hold the plug in, but of course don't want to do that. I'm afraid if I push too hard, I'll break the drywall. Cheap construction. There is some give already. I called the contractor and they will get to it when they can which means two weeks if I'm lucky. Thanks again.

Comment: Hey, I got it to go in!!! Thanks Michael, by wiggling and pushing like you suggested a couple of times it finally went. Thanks again to everyone.

Comment: Thanks also to Ed. You gave me the courage to try more pressure.

Comment: **Always switch off the power** to this type of socket when inserting or removing the plug/pigtail!

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Warloki & Michael K, I never plug something in other than a meter to verify the voltage. 4 prong plugs can be a bugger. I would turn the power off and pull it out then try reinstalling by pushing hard and rocking as you push it may take quite a bit of force. I am a big guy and have had trouble getting them to go in. Pull it back out noticing if you made any progress and try again. After 3 or 4 attempts it will probably go in. Once it is seated then turn the power back on. I say to turn the power off because I have ended up touching the prongs on these type of plugs more than once over the years so if I have trouble inserting the plug the breaker gets turned off.